# Travis CI install boost from source log limitation error

Tags: c++, linux, boost, travis-ci

It is for a while that I am working on a project and I want to build it on travis ci. My project has a dependency to `boost-geometry`, so I tried the following `travis.yml`

```
language: cpp
dist: Xenial
sudo: true
matrix:
  include:
  - os: linux
    env:
      - PYTHON=3.6
      - CXX=g++-5
      - CC=gcc-5
      - CXXFLAGS = "$CXXFLAGS -std=c++14"
#  - os: linux
#    env: CONDA=3.6 CXX=g++ CC=gcc CXXFLAGS = "$CXXFLAGS -std=c++14"
# Boost
addons:
  apt:
    update: true
    packages:
      - libboost-all-dev
      - g++-5

before_install:
  - sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install gcc-5 -y
  - sudo apt-get install g++-5 -y
  - sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev -y
  - sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
  - sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
  - sudo apt-get install python3-pip
  - sudo pip install --user --upgrade pip virtualenv
  - sudo pip install --user setuptools
  - sudo virtualenv -p python3 venv
  - source venv/bin/activate
  - sudo pip install pybind11
  - sudo python3 -m pip install pybind11
  - sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
  - cd src
  - ls
  - cd ../

install:
    - ls $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR
    - sudo python3 setup.py install
    - sudo python3 setup.py sdist
    - sudo pip install --verbose dist/*.tar.gz
script:
- python tests/test.py
```

In this file it gives me a error. which indicates that this file is not installed as part of `boost` geometry library.

`could not find boost/geometry/core/assert.hpp`

So I decided to build boost from source. I used the following file

```
language: cpp
dist: Xenial
sudo: true
matrix:
  include:
  - os: linux
    env:
      - PYTHON=3.6
      - CXX=g++-5
      - CC=gcc-5
      - CXXFLAGS = "$CXXFLAGS -std=c++14"
#  - os: linux
#    env: CONDA=3.6 CXX=g++ CC=gcc CXXFLAGS = "$CXXFLAGS -std=c++14"
# Boost
addons:
  apt:
    update: true
    sources:
      -boost-latest
    packages:
      - libboost-all-dev
      - g++-5

before_install:
  - sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install gcc-5 -y
  - sudo apt-get install g++-5 -y
  - sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev -y
  - sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
  - sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
  - sudo apt-get install python3-pip
  - wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.70.0/boost_1_70_0.tar.gz
  - tar -xzvf boost_1_70_0.tar.gz
  - cd boost_1_70_0
  - sudo ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local --with-libraries=all
  - sudo ./b2 install
  - sudo /bin/bash -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/boost.conf'
  - sudo ldconfig
  - cd ../../
  - sudo pip install --user --upgrade pip virtualenv
  - sudo pip install --user setuptools
  - sudo virtualenv -p python3 venv
  - source venv/bin/activate
  - sudo pip install pybind11
  - sudo python3 -m pip install pybind11
  - sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
  - cd src
  - ls
  - cd ../


    # Inform user that Boost 1.55 was successfully installed
#    echo "Boost 1.55 was successfully installed."


install:
#- |
#  if [ -n "$PYTHON" ]; then
#    sudo apt-get install -qq g++-6
#    sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6 90
    - ls $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR
    - sudo python3 setup.py install
    - sudo python3 setup.py sdist
    - sudo pip install --verbose dist/*.tar.gz
#  elif [ -n "$CONDA" ]; then
#    conda build conda.recipe
#    conda install --use-local pydggrid
#  fi
script:
- python tests/test.py
```

It starts to run but as boost writes logs travis raises the following error

```
The job exceeded the maximum log length, and has been terminated.
```

Well, what can I do to fix this issue? I looked for a flag to avoid boost generating that amount of logs but could not find any. I also tried to find a why to use `apt-get` to install boost-geometry but did not get any chance to find proper package. Can some one help me with this issue?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

well I ended up with this method

```
  - wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.70.0/boost_1_70_0.tar.gz -P $HOME
  - cd $HOME
  - tar -xzvf boost_1_70_0.tar.gz >/dev/null
```

and as boost is header only library I did not compile it, I just added its directory in include section of my make script